# Nuxt/Express API is returning in console but not browser

Tags: express, nuxt.js, jsforce

I'm quite new to this whole backend business and I'm wondering if anyone can see where I'm going wrong. I've got an express server in my **Nuxt** app which is serving out an API. When I run the localhost:3000/api/salesforce/:id route - my vscode terminal generates a response - but it doesn't show up on the browser. Which in turn makes it inaccessible to Nuxt.

In my **nuxt.config.js**:

```
  serverMiddleware: {
    '/api': '~/api'
  },
```

**/api/index.js**:

```
const express = require('express')

// Create express instance
const app = express()

// Require API routes
const users = require('./routes/users')
const test = require('./routes/test')
const salesforce = require('./routes/salesforce')

// Import API Routes
app.use(users)
app.use(test)
app.use(salesforce)

// Export express app
module.exports = app

// Start standalone server if directly running
if (require.main === module) {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
  app.listen(port, () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`API server listening on port ${port}`)
  })
}
```

Then in **/api/routes/salesforce.js**:

```
const e = require('express')
const { Router } = require('express')

const router = Router()

const jsforce = require('jsforce');

// require the .env file for login
require('dotenv').config();
const { SF_USERNAME, SF_PASSWORD, SF_TOKEN, SF_LOGIN_URL } = process.env;
if (!(SF_USERNAME && SF_PASSWORD && SF_TOKEN && SF_LOGIN_URL)) {
  console.error(
      'Cannot start app: missing mandatory configuration. Check your .env file.'
  );
  process.exit(-1);
}

const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
  loginUrl: SF_LOGIN_URL
});

conn.login(SF_USERNAME, SF_PASSWORD + SF_TOKEN, err => {
  if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(-1);
  }
});

// get OPPORTUNITY specific
router.get('/salesforce/:id', function (req, res, next) {

  const id = req.params.id
  console.log(req.params.id)

  const sfData = conn.query(`SELECT Id, Name, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Name = '` + id + `'`, (err, res)=>{
    if(err){ 
      console.log(err)
      return "error";
    } else {
      console.log(res.records[0]) 
      let sanitisedData = res.records[0]
      return sanitisedData;
    }
  })
  res.json(sfData.json)

})
```

If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong that would be greatly appreciated, I'm kind of stuck here.

Comment: Did you even need a Node.js server here? Aren't you pinging a remote URL?

Comment: I am, but I can't get the query to work in a vue file, whether it's fetch or async data. It always returns a 404. I've been able to access other api's quite easily but this salesforce one is stubborn. The best luck I've had is accessing it from an express server route and then pinging my route, which loads in the terminal but not on the page for some reason.  It might be something to do with how I'm sending the final payload, but I don't have a lot of experience with express (the res.json(sfData.json) part)

Comment: Wait, what are you doing with `conn.query`? Some SQL query? Whaaaat? Do you have the documentation for the API?

Comment: It's Salesforce's 'kind of SQL' called 'SOQL'. At the moment I'm just trying to request an Opportunity record by it's name. 

Documentation for how to do SOQL queries: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins/get-started-with-soql-queries

Comment: Hm, that kind of code should probably be on another backend service, plugged to a local database or alike. Having it in Nuxt is not what I'd recommend because it's "too close" for the front-end to either be secure or efficient. Usually, you never do SQL that close, especially not on the front-end.